# HeroKu Discord.py.json Not Updating on GitHub

Tags: python, json, github, heroku, discord.py

So I recently made a bot that stores information into a .json file and it works pretty well on Visual Code Studio. But the problem is im hosting through GitHub on Heroku so when I run my code Heroku takes the json file and using its data updates IT'S **OWN** json file not the actual file in GitHub. So when I restart HeroKu for a update it re-reads the json file **replacing** the file it used to store and erasing the data and replacing with the json in GitHub which had not changed at all. Is there a way to backup the json file and potentially save some information? Or another way to store information on discord.py that is also compatible with Heroku? Btw I do not have access to Command Prompt Heroku, only the "Run Console" on the website

- EpicGoodBoi
  Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can create copy with .bkp extenion before doing any processing

Comment: Can you expand on that? Like I said I only have the "Run Console" on the HeroKu website so do I put my file name then .bkp for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

`Heroku` doesn't actually edit `GitHub` - it just clones it's code from your linked repository onto it's server and runs it there. If you need it to update on your `GitHub` repository, then I would use the [Github Rest API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest).

**Edit:** Here is the documentation: [Create or update file contents](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I need assistants

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand most of what its saying, because it's not relating to discord.py, so it is the code I change or repository I change?

Comment: @EpicGoodBoi If you want the repo to change, then you will have to update your code to use the `GitHub REST Api` (see the link in my answer). [Here](https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/) is a good tutorial on how to send requests.